# Smooth functions with equal derivatiesof all orders in one point

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion, smooth-functions

Let's assume that $f,g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are smooth functions  and

$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}:\, |f^{(n)}(x)|, |g^{(n)}(x)| < 1 $

prove that if $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\, f^{(n)}(0) = g^{(n)}(0)$, then f = g.

I presumed that if two smooth functions have a point $a$ in which $\forall n\in\mathbb{N\cup\{0\}} \,\,f^{(n)}(a) = g^{(n)}(a)$, then they are equal because their Taylor series are infinite and each term is equal. Later, I found a counter example: $\displaystyle  f(x) = \begin{cases}e^{- \frac{1}{x^2}} &\text{for } x \neq 0
    \\ 0 & \text{when } x=0 \end{cases}\,\,$ and $\,\,g(x) =0$

I understand it but I don't really see why my initial presumption is wrong. Can anyone explain it better or suggest some reading? As for the proof, my final idea is to inspect Taylor series of $h(x) = f(x)-g(x)$ and prove that Lagrange's form of the remainder converges to 0. Would that be a correct proof?

Comment: How do you define “smooth function”?

Comment: [A smooth function is a function that has derivatives of all orders everywhere in its domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness)

Comment: Those functions are not a counter example. The derivatives of $f$ are not uniformly bounded by $1$. Under the condition $\forall x\in \mathbb{R},\ |f^{(n)}(x)|<1$ the Taylor series of $F$ does converge to $f$. Look at the Lagrange form of the remainder.

Comment: @user647486 counter example to "if two smooth functions have a point $a$ in which $\forall n\in\mathbb{N\cup\{0\}} \,\,f^{(n)}(a) = g^{(n)}(a)$, then they are equal"

Comment: Ah! I see. Yes, for that it is the classic example. What saves you from that phenomenon are the bounds on the derivatives, which make the function belong to the class of real analytic functions. These are, in particular determined by the derivatives at a point. A more general condition is both belonging to a [quasi-analytic class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-analytic_function), which is also equivalent to some less restrictive bounds on the derivatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a *real* function, even if smooth, may not agree with its Taylor series as you have seen in this famous example. Functions that agree with their Taylor series are called analytic. The situation is much better in *complex* analysis as complex differentiability already implies that a function is smooth and equal to its Taylor series.

As for your second question: Yes, you can prove this using the Lagrange form of the remainder.